# How to check only if the user allowed the permission

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am using a third party library (https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-intro) to show the introduction screens to the application, with that same library before finishing the introduction I ask for a permission to execute an AsyncTask from MainActivity,

But I do not know how to make to verify if the permission is allowed and after verifying to execute the action of the AsyncTask.

I explain how my code is, I hope you can understand me

This is the code of the Splash, start of the application:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I have an ActivityResult to be able to show the introduction Slides for the first time and to be able to save the Sharedpreferences and not show it again.
This part of my code

```
private class FetchNewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL( GlobalConfig.API_Content_Url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

            }catch( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("sticker_packs");
                cloudArray=jArray;
                CompaireStickerSetsNew();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                flashbar.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_INTRO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                        .putBoolean(PREF_KEY_FIRST_START, false)
                        .apply();

            } else {
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                        .putBoolean(PREF_KEY_FIRST_START, true)
                        .apply();


                //User cancelled the intro so we'll finish this activity too.
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have an Activity MainIntroActivity where I use the third party library and where I show the Slides and in one specific one I ask for permission

```
    public static final String EXTRA_PERMISSIONS = "com.heinrichreimersoftware.materialintro.demo.EXTRA_PERMISSIONS";
    public static final String EXTRA_SCROLLABLE = "com.heinrichreimersoftware.materialintro.demo.EXTRA_SCROLLABLE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MainActivity mainClase = new MainActivity();


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean permissions = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, true);
        boolean scrollable = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SCROLLABLE, false);


        setButtonBackVisible(false);
        setButtonNextVisible(true);

        addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()
                .title(R.string.title_slide_1)
                .description(R.string.description_1)
                .image(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .background(R.color.black)
                .backgroundDark(R.color.colorAccent)
                .scrollable(false)
                .build());

        addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()
                .title(R.string.title_slide_2)
                .description(R.string.description_2)
                .image(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .background(R.color.black)
                .backgroundDark(R.color.colorAccent)
                .scrollable(false)
                .build());

        final Slide permissionsSlide;
        if (permissions) {
            permissionsSlide = new SimpleSlide.Builder()
                    .title(R.string.title_permissions)
                    .description(R.string.description_permissions)
                    .background(R.color.black)
                    .backgroundDark(R.color.colorAccent)
                    .scrollable(scrollable)
                    .permissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE})
                    .build();
            addSlide(permissionsSlide);
        } else {
            permissionsSlide = null;

        }

        addOnNavigationBlockedListener(new OnNavigationBlockedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationBlocked(int position, int direction) {
                View contentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                if (contentView != null) {
                    Slide slide = getSlide(position);

                    if (slide == permissionsSlide) {
                        Snackbar.make(contentView, R.string.label_grant_permissions, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then my problem is that when in MainActivity I don't know how to verify that the permission is already allowed by the user, then already granted the permission I should be able to execute the AsyncTask that I have in MainActivity "new FetchNewData().execute();)"

Any opinion or advice will be appreciated, greetings

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to use this library.

[git link](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions.git)

This library provides the short and simple code you want. This library provides you to handle both situations, allowed or denied.

add this `implementation` to your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
```

add in your code

```
  String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
String rationale = "Please provide location permission so that you can ...";
Permissions.Options options = new Permissions.Options()
        .setRationaleDialogTitle("Info")
        .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning");

Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, rationale, options, new PermissionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onGranted() {
        // do your task.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        // permission denied, block the feature.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` in your `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

Check whether permission was granted or not in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` If not then check `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` which returns either `true` or `false`

Sample Code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){ 
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
switch (requestCode) {
    case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST:
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // permission was granted :)
            downloadFile();
        } else {
            // permission was not granted
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showStoragePermissionRationale();
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_storage_permission_snackbar), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (getActivity() == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getActivity().getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        Fragment.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
        break;
  }
}
```